# Hibernate saving a java object of @Non-Entity child class of @Entity parent class

Tags: java, hibernate

I have two classes

Parent:

```
@Entity
public class Rule{
 private String id;
 private String name;
 private String content;

 // setter and getters here
}
```

Child:

```
// this is not an entity class (no table exists for this)
public class SignalRule extends Rule{
 private String positionType;
 private String TraderOperation operation;

  // setters and getters here
}
```

What I m doing is:

```
// instantiate an object of SignalRule
SignalRule signal=new SignalRule();
// set properties
```

Then I m trying to save the object via hibernate `EntityManager` :

```
commonDAO.save(signal);
```

save method code is following:

```
public void save(Object entity) {

    // TODO: check how to setup transaction support based on annotations
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
    EntityTransaction tx = null;
    try {
        tx = em.getTransaction();
        tx.begin();
        em.persist(entity);
        tx.commit();
    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        if (tx != null && tx.isActive())
            tx.rollback();
        logger.error("Can't save object " + entity.getClass() + " "
                + entity + "to DB", e);
        throw e;
    } finally {
        em.close();
    }
}
```

It says:

ERROR [CommonDAO] Can't save object class app.client.shared.bre.model.SignalRule app.client.shared.bre.model.SignalRule@5763ca80to DB
[INFO] java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown entity: app.client.shared.bre.model.SignalRule
[INFO]  at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:878)
[INFO]  at app.server.persistence.CommonDAO.save(CommonDAO.java:69)

What am I doing wrong? Can't I save the child object. ? Its necessary to create an object of child class: `SignalRule`, and save it in `Rule` enity. isn't possible? Can you please suggest me a solution for that?
Thanks!

Comment: If there is no table for SignalRule  Then What is the Use of Saving that

Comment: basically. I m converting SignalRule in json and saving it in a column of Rule table. That's what needed.

Comment: What is the value you are saving in Rule Table? Is any of the field of signalRule

Comment: Sorry for bothering you......I figured it out. Thanks for your response. Mcuh appreciated. !!

Comment: Please provide what is the mistake you have done or solution for the problem as Answer here. It might help others who see this problem

Comment: @SR-Rehman Right now I have the same problem. Please describe what was the solution for you?